# Magento2: Override block not working

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

So i am trying to override the `module-customer -> Block -> Account -> AuthorizationLink.php`

What i did is:

I made a folder Customer in:

```
app -> code -> Theme -> Customer
```

in the Customer Folder there is 2 more folders: `etc and Block/Account`

in the etc folder there is xml called di

**di.xml:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" type="AXAStudios\Customer\Block\AuthorizationLink" />
</config>
```

and in my `Block/Account` i have a file called: `AuthorizationLink.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace AXAStudios\Customer\Block\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;

/**
 * Customer authorization link
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{
    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    protected $_customerUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper
     */
    protected $_postDataHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn()
            ? $this->_customerUrl->getLogoutUrl()
            : $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Sign In');
    }

     /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabelOrder() {
        return __('My Orders');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve params for post request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostParams()
    {
        return $this->_postDataHelper->getPostData($this->getHref());
    }

    /**
     * Is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SORT_ORDER);
    }
}
```

But whenever i upload it to the server and flush cache there is nothing that changed.

so any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try generating the classes by setup:di:compile?

Comment: You are saying that you create a folder structure of app/code/Theme/Customer but in the preference, you are specifying the type to be AXAStudios\Customer\Block\AuthorizationLink. What is the name of the module that you are creating? Please check it and provide the correct implementations in the question.

Comment: @MathanagopalS in **app\code**  i've made a folder **Customer** in the Customer folder there is 2 more folders: **Block** and **etc**. In the Block file i have a file that i want to override from the vendor and that is the: **AuthorizationLink.php** from the module-customer. In the etc i have 2 files **di.xml** and **module.xml**. But i have no idea to do this and if i am working in the right folder

Comment: Check this out - [https://github.com/Mathanagopal97/Override-block-not-working](https://github.com/Mathanagopal97/Override-block-not-working)

Comment: @MathanagopalS Thanks, i placed this in mijn `app -> code`. Is this the right way or do i have to place this in my `app -> design -> frontend -> AXAStudios -> axadesign ->` my current theme

Comment: @TechGaz7 If you use blocks and plugins and di.xml, it is always best to place them in app/code. So is the code working for you?

Comment: @MathanagopalS Okay good i placed this in my app/code but now i get a error whenever i run `php bin/magento s:up`. And the error is `Invalid template file: 'account/link/authorization.phtml' in module: 'AXAStudios_Customer' block's name: 'authorization-link-login'`

Comment: Looks like we have to create a template file. Just copy the contents of ```<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml``` to 

```app/code/AXAStudios/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml```

Comment: Check my github page. It seems that for overriding a block, we have to override the combination of block.php, block's xml and block's template file.

Comment: @MathanagopalS This worked for me appr it wow!

Comment: So I will convert this an answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - https://github.com/Mathanagopal97/Override-block-not-working.

It seems that for overriding a block, we have to override the combination of block.php, block's xml and block's template file.

Comment: Thankyou!, Got 1 more questions can i also add my own functions to the block i override? because i only apply's to functions that already exist as an example i want to make a function called: getLabelOrder where it returns 'My Orders' as an example

Comment: Yes, you can add your own methods if you want. But, then you have to call that either in the template file of yours or in some other method that you are overriding. The concept is simple and all basic rules of inheritance will apply here.

Comment: Alright thanks. I did but it did not work like i searched up or tried on my manners maybe if you can add this to your github repository quick. Man you saved my life hahah thankyou!

Comment: Haha, I have added the code to my repository. Check it out.